# g:submitButton- onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, grails, onclick, tags, submit-button

I have the following `g:submitButton`:

```
 <g:submitButton name="next" class="signup-button skyblue-btn pull-right pl-pr-36" value="${message(code:"buttons.ok")}" onclick="return showSpinnerSignUp()"/>
```

I define the `showSpinnerSignUp()` in the JS file:

```
$(function() {
    function showSpinnerSignUp(){
        $('.spinner-ctn').show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

The spinner is not displayed (the `onclick` doesn't work).

Comment: Does the rendered HTML contain the `onclick="return showSpinnerSignUp()"`?

Comment: Not sure it is your case, but submit should refresh the page making any DOM modification in onclick useless. Instead try to use ajax. (to check my idea, change the return value of showSpinnerSignUp to false, if you see the spinner, I was correct)

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of a form submission in the browser. You have registered a `showSpinnerSignUp()` method on the click of a button while the click on that same button is responsible for submitting the enclosing form.

Since the browser's built-in behavior for submitting forms works by making a full roundtrip to the server, that immediately interrupts your code execution of `onclick` event because your browser is navigating away from your current page.

This can be simulated as if you had clicked your button and refreshed the page immediately. Your current setup might work when you deploy this to the production server, but the possibility of working this setup locally is low because a local development server used to run on a faster machine  so the page refresh time of form submission is quite faster.

To verify this happening, open your browser's console and call the method `showSpinnerSignUp()` directly (remember to remove it from `$(function() {})` temporarily) and see if the spinner is showing up.

Also, there is an option to `Preserve Logs` which keeps the Javascript console logs even after page refresh. So, put a simple `console.log()` inside your method call and then try hitting that button. You'll see your method is called but no spinner is displayed due to form submission.